# How do I move Windows 11 64 bit page and hibernation files?

Tags: windows-11, pagefile

I have a notebook with 16 GB memory and 2 SSD drives. The primary drive (C:) has only 250 GB, the secondary (D:) has 1 TB. Both are BitLocker protected (its a notebook).

I have installed most software (many software development tools that takes hours to reinstall) on C: and the C: disk becomes full when I use too much virtual memory (which could be 24 GB).

The easiest choice would be to move pagefile.sys (and hiberfil.sys) to the d: drive.
But how do I do this? I can change the virtual memory settings to use drive D:.

But the systems brings an error on next reboot (translated, message on my system is in German):

```
A temporary pagefile was created because there was a problem configuring the pagefile.
```

Is there an alternative to reinstalling the whole system?

Comment: Have you considered adding more RAM or storage instead? I have a feeling you won't be able to store the pagefile on a BitLocker-protected disk, because it only gets unlocked much later than the pagefile initialization happens... (This will _definitely_ apply to the hibernation image, which must be accessible while the OS is not running at all.) On the other hand, moving the whole OS to a new SSD is fairly easy.

Comment: @user1686 Does [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/bitlocker-drive-encryption-bde-enables-the-pagefileonosvolume-registry-setting-on-windows-b01c257e-1977-f892-fdcf-1a5ba444b771), or something like it, not apply to Windows 10/11 as well _(it doesn't list OSes after 8.1 and I don't use Bitlocker so I can't verify)_

Answer (score 4):

You can't move the hibernation file `hiberfil.sys`. It must must reside
on the system partition, as it's used very early in the boot and before
other disks become available.

To move the page-file:

- Run `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`
- In Advanced tab, under Performance, click Settings...
- Position to the Advanced tab
- Under Virtual memory, click Change...
- Uncheck "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives"
  and choose your disk and amount to allocate
- Click OK and reboot.

Comment: That is what I did. But it produces the error described in the issue on next reboot.

Comment: Try to set Windows to No paging file, reboot, delete pagefile.sys if it exists on both disks, then create anew the pagefile, reboot again.

Comment: The error message also appears when I disable paging and reboot (although a pagefile.sys does not exist in that case). After reenabling the page file on the D: drive and rebooting the message appears again and pagefile is still on the c: drive

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Do also `chkdsk`.

Comment: Running this commands does not change the problem. When rebooting without virtual storage, the c:pagefile.sys is gone but d:pagefile.sys exists and can not be deleted. When activating virtual memory from d:, a 14 GB pagefile.sys is created together with a 4 GB pagefile.sys on d:

Comment: Very strange. Try doing all this while booting in Safe mode.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use Hibernation (aka suspend to disk)?

If not, you can get rid of `hiberfil.sys` entirely by disabling Hibernation. To do this, run the following command from an elevated command prompt:

`powercfg /H off`

To turn Hibernation back on, simply use:

`powercfg /H on`

While I'm aware that this does not directly answer your question, it is still worth mentioning as not everybody is using suspend to disk and therefore can free up several GBs on their disks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps creating a new partition dedicated to swap space might solve your issue.  Create a new drive on the D: drive (your second 1TB SSD), with a generous size (50 GB?).  Once you format the drive, ensure it is **not** Bitlocker protected. Use the virtual memory settings to assign that drive as the swap space location (set both initial and max size to the maximum, -5 MB).  Reboot, and see if this sorts your assignment issues. It will definitely resolve your low disk space issues.

Another tip to help ameliorate your space issue is to move your TEMP directories to your D: drive as well, as that is constantly changing.